# How to hide (but keep enabled) Action Center icon from the taskbar

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons, notification-area, action-center

I am using Windows 10, and normally in recent Windows versions, I can hide system icons as well as app icons in the notification area (previously known as system tray). A little triangle button appears when icons are hidden, which I can click to reveal them in a small fly-out menu.

With Windows 10, there's a new feature called Action Center, which I find is quite handy and useful, as it collects notifications unlike Windows 7, where it used to be dismissed and lost automatically. My gripe is that Windows 10 developers did not integrate the Action Center icon with the icon hiding mechanisms applied to other system icons like Power, Network, Volume etc.

I looked online, and I find a lot of guides and hacks to remove Action Center icon from the taskbar or disable Action Center icon itself. But nothing so far on just hiding the icon.

*To recap:*

- I don't want to remove the Action Center icon completely from the taskbar.
- I don't want to disable the Action Center feature.
- I just want to hide the icon from the taskbar, so that it goes into the fly-out menu of hidden icons.

  - This would normally be done in *"Select which icons appear on the taskbar"* but Action Center is not in the list.

**Is this possible? How can I do it?**

I'm also willing to try a third party application (AutoHotkey <strike>doing `Win-A`</strike>*, maybe?) that will sit in the tray (with the same icon) that will pull up the Action Center pane, so that <strike>I can just disable the system icon for Action Center (under *"Turn system icons on or off"*).</strike>*

* Apparently this wouldn't work because disabling the system icon also makes it impossible to reach Action Center using the keyboard shortcut. It appears that it disables the Action Center itself.